# Is there are tool that can store and retrieve monitor arrangements as presets?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, display

I'm working with a MacBook at different locations where monitors are then in a different positions relative to the MacBook's screen. As a result I have to rearrange the monitor setup every time I use a different workplace.

Is there a built-in way in OS X or a tool to save an arrangement and easily restore it, preferably from the menu bar?

Answer (score 3):

You should try [SwitchResX](http://www.madrau.com/).  It allows you to create *Display Sets* defining many variables like placement relative to other displays, setting which display is the primary, etc.  [Here](http://www.madrau.com/srx_howtouseit/srx_howtouseit/srx_display_sets.html) is the *Display Set* page showing the options.

It even has the ability to set a keyboard shortcut to each *Display Set* so you can quickly switch layouts, resolutions, etc.